# CMake ignores library_output_name

Tags: cmake, libraries

I have a simple CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9) project (sample)

add_library(Shared SHARED foo.c)
set_target_properties(Shared PROPERTIES library_output_name libdemo.so.1.2.3)
```

I want my library to be called `libdemo.so.1.2.3` but it is being called `libShared.so`.  How can I get this file to name the library as I want?  Since I want to add a static version of the same library I don't just want to change the `add_library()`directive since the static library will have the same name with just a different extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing `set_target_properties()` line to be:

> set_target_properties(Shared PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME demo.so.1.2.3)

solves the problem.

No error is generated by the previous method but it silently ignores the line.

Answer (score 1):

set `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME` for shared libraries

set `OUTPUT_NAME` for static libraries

sample code from [ShivaVG](https://github.com/vpxyz/ShivaVG/pull/4)

```
# create object
add_library(ShivaVG_objlib OBJECT
  ${libShivaVG_SOURCES})
set_property(TARGET ShivaVG_objlib
  PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE 1)

# create library (static)
add_library(ShivaVGStatic
  STATIC $<TARGET_OBJECTS:ShivaVG_objlib>)
set_target_properties(ShivaVGStatic
  PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME ShivaVG)

# create library (shared)
add_library(ShivaVGShared
  SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:ShivaVG_objlib>)
target_link_libraries(ShivaVGShared
  ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLEW_LIBRARIES} -lm)
set_target_properties(ShivaVGShared
  PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME ShivaVG)
```

this will produce `ShivaVG.so` and `ShivaVG.a`